# Change font colour for positive/negative values that are imported from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, colors

Here is my code that allows me to import from my Google Sheet by specifying the column titles.

```js
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

httpGetAsync('https://spreadsheet.glitch.me/?key=1JBbAHH1DFtO1r56lr94lUqd8H7qPcHncJskcPq0r96o', function(response) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response);

  document.getElementById("btm").innerHTML = json[0].btm;
  document.getElementById("AvgPoints").innerHTML = json[0].AvgPoints;
  document.getElementById("Overtakes").innerHTML = json[0].Overtakes;
  document.getElementById("podium").innerHTML = json[0].podium;
  document.getElementById("highest").innerHTML = json[0].highest;
});
```

This allows me to put `<div id="AvgPoints"></div>` in my HTML and it populates based on the value in my Google Sheets document. My aim is to colour the font green for positive numbers (including 0) and red for negative numbers. Is this possible bearing in mind there isn't actually a number between the `<div></div>` tags in my HTMl code? If it is, I'd also be interested to learn how to add +/- characters infront of the imported number based on if it is positive/negative as well. Sorry I'm trying to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the value to a number, check for positive or negative and then you could assign a pre-made CSS class to the element, along with possibly prepending the appropriate `+` symbol (I assume negative values already have `-` in front of them).

```js
// Get all the divs that should be styled into an array
let divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#btm, #AvgPoints, #Overtakes, #podium, #highest"));

// Loop the array
divs.forEach(function(div){
  // Convert text to number and test for positive/negative
  if((+div.textContent) >= 0){
    div.classList.add("positive"); // Apply positive style
    div.textContent = "+" + div.textContent; 
  } else {
    div.classList.add("negative"); // Apply negative style  
  }
});
```

```css
.positive { color: green; }
.negative { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="btm">135</div>
<div id="AvgPoints">0</div>
<div id="Overtakes">-17</div>
<div id="podium">1</div>
<div id="highest">-125</div>
```

Comment: Ah! I see perfect. Is there a way to do this without copying and pasting all of that for every ID I have - as .getElementById can only have 1 ID in it. how could i use something like document.querySelectorAll to apply your code to multiple id's at once? Appreciate your help!

Comment: @LiamThompson You'd need something that all the elements have in common, like a class or you could use multiple selectors, like `document.querySelectorAll("#AvgPoints, #somethingElse, #somethingElse")` and then just loop over the resulting node list and use my code in the loop.

Comment: @LiamThompson If my answer was helpful, please "up vote" it and consider marking it as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm trying this at the moment., and have managed to get the first id to work. Can you spot why the other isn't working?

`let divs = document.querySelectorAll("#btm", "#AvgPoints");

[].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
   // Convert text to number and test for positive/negative
  if((+div.textContent) >= 0){
      div.classList.add("positive"); // Apply positive style
  } else {
      div.classList.add("negative"); // Apply negative style  
  }
});
`

Comment: @LiamThompson You shouldn't be putting each `id` in its own set of quotes. It should just be: `let divs = document.querySelectorAll("#btm, #AvgPoints");` as one comma separated string. Otherwise, you are passing multiple arguments to `.querySelectorAll()`, which it doesn't accept.

Comment: @LiamThompson I've updated my answer to show how you'd do all the divs.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code! Please view my codepen [link](https://codepen.io/liamdthompson/pen/OqeVxa) the negative colouring is not being applied?

Comment: @LiamThompson It's because the styling code is running before the data comes back from your AJAX call. You need to move all my code into the AJAX success callback.

Comment: so I would need to put into the callback by using something like somewait() to delay your code until the callback has happened?

Comment: @LiamThompson You could, but more simply, just move my code into the AJAX callback.